# Size of neighbouring data a modern computer caches for locality favour

Tags: performance, caching, optimization, cpu-architecture

I have a continuous **memory** of 1024 buffers, each buffer sizes 2K bytes. I use a linked list to keep record of available buffers (Buffer here can be thought of being used by Producer and Consumer). After some operations, the order of buffers in the link list becomes random.

The modern computer architecture favours compact data, locality a lot. It caches neighbouring data when a location needs to be accessed. The cache-line of my computer is 64(corrected from 64K) bytes.

Question 1. For my case, is there a lot of cache misses due to my access pattern is random?

Question 2. What is the size of neighbouring data a modern computer caches? I think if you access a location in an array of integers, it will cache neighbouring integers. But my unit data (2K) is much larger than int (4). So, I am not sure how many neighbours will be cached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all I doubt that "*The cache-line of my computer is 64K bytes*". It's most likely to be 64 Bytes only. Let me try to answer your questions:

**Question 1. For my case, is there a lot of cache misses due to my access pattern is random?**

Not necessarily. It depends on how many operations you do on a buffer once it is cached.

- So if you cache a 2K buffer and do lots of sequential work on it your
  cache hit rate would be good. As Paul suggested, this *works even better with hardware prefetching enabled*.
- However if you constantly jump between    buffers and do relatively
  low amount of work on each buffer, the    cache hit rate will drop.
  However 1024 x 2KB = 2MB so that could be a size for an L2 cache (*if you have also L3, then L2 is generally smaller*). So even
  if you miss L1, there's a high chance    that in both cases you will
  hit L2.

**Question 2. What is the size of neighbouring data a modern computer caches?**

Usually the number of neighbors fetched is given by the cache line size. If the line size is 64B, you could fetch 16 integer values. So on each read, you fill a cache line. However you need to take into consideration **prefetching**. *If your CPU detects that the memory reads are sequential, it will prefetch more neighbors and bring more cache lines in advance.*

Hope this helps!

Comment: L2 caches are often smaller than 2 MiB (e.g., 2nd through 4th generation Intel Core processors have 256 KiB L2s). It might also be worth mentioning that the 64 byte cache line is aligned. Also, mentioning hardware prefetching in the first bullet point (e.g., "good, especially with hardware prefetching.") in addition to the later explanation *might* be an improvement.

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton Thanks for your comments. I'll fine tune the post. Regarding L2 size, that's debatable. On mobile SoC's where L2 is the last level, it's usually larger. ARM and Intel Atom can go easily up to 2MB. Where you have also L3, you are right.

Comment: Sadly, I cannot reward your edits with an upvote since I already upvoted the post. (Yes, when L2 is LLC it tends to be larger and AMD's FX processors have 2MiB L2 plus L3. I did write "often".☺)